# Using Event Calendar web part with multiple calendars in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010

I added the Event Calendar web part but I have two calendars on this site so it's not working.  Is there a way to specify which calendar I want it to display or is it even possible to use the calendar web part when there are two calendars on a site in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: What is the "Event Calendar" web part? Is that a custom/3rd party web part?

Comment: did you try to have a look at the Calendar Overlay feature? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: I'm not working with overlays.  This is a basic calendar that is the default when we create a site, however on this site we have 2 calendars.  Typically when I add the calendar web part it displays a mini-version of the calendar on the page I add the web part to.  When I have 2 calendars nothing is populating in my web part so I'm thinking the web part needs some way to distinguish which calendar I want to display.  I don't know if this is possible.  A good example of what it looks like can be found here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78532/Event-Calendar-Listing-Web-Part-SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.  After I added the event calendar web part, I had to edit web part.  Under the configuration section I put the name of the calendar I wanted to display and the URL.